# Why does angular.injector(["ng","myTestApp"]) and angular.injector(["ng"]) return different objects?

Tags: angularjs

I have created an module as:-

`angular.module('myTestApp', [])`

Now in the console I call:

```
var initInjector = angular.injector(["ng"]);
var initInjector2 = angular.injector(["ng","myTestApp"]);
```

I expected the `initInjector2 === initInjector` would return `true` but it returns `false`.

What is the reason for that?